# I read Max Black's argument against the identity of indiscernibles and I'm now doubting the axiom of choice for finite sets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Help!

His argument basically goes that two identical spheres in an otherwise empty universe are indiscernible, but not identical. He also mentions the axiom of choice in passing. This got me thinking about the choice function for finite sets: does it even make sense to say that we can select an element *x* from finite *S* if *x* is indiscernible? Does *x* even exist as a choice if it is indiscernible from the other elements of the set (but unidentical)? It almost seems for a second that it has become necessary to invoke the axiom of choice for finite sets.

Comment: Indiscernible from what?

Comment: Indiscernible from the other elements of the set, but not identical. You're right, that was some sloppy ambiguous wording.

Comment: Well the last question still doesn't make a lot of sense to me (it could be that it’s discernible in some sets it’s in but not others). Also, selecting an object from a finite set doesn’t require the axiom of choice. (Nor does selecting one from an infinite set.) that’s not what the axiom of choice for finite sets is. Indiscernibility does have a lot to do with why choice is independent from the other axioms, though. But in general I think your question isn’t about math at present, so voting to close.

Comment: Your question seems related to type theory. For example, the type Bool := {true, false} is constructed by taking two meaningless atoms and deciding arbitrarily that one of them has one meaning and the other has another. Under the axiom of univalence, the type "Bool = Bool" (that is, the type of all witnesses to Bool being equal to Bool) has *two* members - the usual one ("everything is equal to itself"), and the negation operation ("true and false have no intrinsic meaning that could distinguish them from each other, so we might as well swap them round").

Comment: But crucially only one of those two members is *uniformly definable*: we had to know specifically that we were dealing with Bool before we could define the other witness to "Bool = Bool". There's only one proof that A = A which holds for *all* A, and that's "everything is by definition equal to itself". None of this is really an answer to your question, but it seems similar to what you're looking at.

Comment: That's fair on requiring the axiom of choice. I guess the correct terminology for what I'm losing my mind over would actually be to argue that the ability to select an element from a finite set does require the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Dunedubby ok, that makes more sense (you should probably edit that into the question). I’ll retract my close vote, since I think clarifying that will have some mathematical content, though I probably won’t chime in myself.

Comment: @PatrickStevens thanks for the excellent type theory input! I am not too familiar with type theory but it does seem quite relevant.

Comment: "$S$ is nonempty" is short for "there exists an object $x$ such that $x\in S$", and "let $x$ be an element of $S$" just introduces a term $x$ and a premise $x\in S$ for use in subsequent deductive steps. Do you feel that this could lead to an error?

Comment: Any other day I would've happily agreed. But now I'm not so sure that nonempty *S* necessarily means that "there exists an object *x* such that *x ∈ S*". I suppose it almost seems that by the time we select which of the two spheres to be the "*x*" we've already lost track of which one we picked. Assuming that the observer does not violate the symmetry of the universe. Unless we invoke the axiom of choice.

Comment: Another argument that gets me is that it's not immediately clear that the two spheres are well-ordered, so equivalently the axiom of choice is not immediately clearly true unless we expressly invoke it.

Comment: In my view, we use the standard framework of set theory because it can simulate the logical properties of a wide variety of mathematical structures (including notions of indistinguishability) and is somewhat intuitive. It's a convenient formalism, not a reflection of metaphysical truth. You could develop an alternative system of reasoning about sets in which the concepts of "nonempty" and "exists" are not related in the standard way, but this won't be directly relevant to the existing field of set theory.

Comment: That's a fair point. Aren't indistinguishable/identical items generally ignored by set theory though? Since usually indistinguishable is equivalent to identical. In any case, I guess my curiosity is more so that there could be interesting behavior even with finite sets in the "relatively" rare systems where the axiom of choice is not included. Or maybe I'm having one confused and crazy day haha

Comment: The axiom of choice is used to make infinitely many choices simultaneously, but making a single choice is provided by a [rule of logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation). You're right that set theory (via [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)) ensures that no two sets are exactly the same. We can still use set theory to build tools to study [symmetric structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism), including symmetric mathematical universes in the context of [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory).

Comment: I think what I was bothered with was that it may make sense sometimes to reject some rules of logic (in such a way that the axiom of choice would have to fill the ensuing gap). I think I found what I was looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, I think what it boils down to is: in regular ZF set theory and most set theories built on classical logic, the ability to choose from a finite set is guaranteed from the rules of logic only (not requiring the axiom of choice). So in that scenario my question is nonsense.

However, we can enter a paradigm where we reject that a choice function exists for e.g. the two spheres scenario. This is constructive mathematics, where we reject one of the rules of classical logic (the excluded middle). We can then develop a new set theory according to that new logic system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory.

Thanks [@Karl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/279914/karl) for helping point me in the right direction.